# How to test React state after calling a component method that updates state - using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Enzyme newbie here. I am trying to test if the state of a React component is being updated after calling a method on that component.

This is a snippet of the component that I am testing:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    recipes: {},
    user: null
  };

  handleUnauth = () => {
    this.setState({
      user: null
    });
  };

  render() {
   //render children, pass down methods as props etc...
  }

}
```

Below is the test:

```js
import createRouterContext from 'react-router-test-context';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import expect from 'expect';
import React from 'react';

import App from 'App';  //import with webpack alias

describe('App', () => {

  let wrapper, context;

  beforeEach(() => {
    context = createRouterContext();
    wrapper = mount(<App/>, { context });
  });

  it('should remove logged in user details on logout', () => {
    const user = {
      uid: 'abc123',
      name: 'John Doe'
    };

    wrapper.setState({ user }, () => {
      wrapper.instance().handleUnauth();
      const userState = wrapper.state('user');
      expect(userState).toEqual(null);
    });

  });

});
```

My test fails with the following error:

[image]

I understand that updating of state is not synchronous but I am not sure if that has something to do with this or if there are better ways to test this using Enzyme. Would be super grateful if someone can please point me in the right direction. Oh and I tried this by calling `wrapper.update()` right after calling `wrapper.instance().handleUnauth()` in the test but this too didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you call `wrapper.update().state('user')`?

Comment: @OrB just tried it with `wrapper.update().state('user')` - it didn't work. The app works fine - I can see that the user value is set to null on logging out, when inspecting with React DevTools but it doesn't work in the test.

Comment: @Larrydx please check the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`React#setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate),

**setState(updater, [callback])**

> `setState()` enqueues changes to the component state.
>   The `setState` doesn't immediately update the state. `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback `(setState(updater, callback))`

**Solution 1:**

Remove callback from `setState`;

```
      wrapper.setState({ user });
      wrapper.instance().handleUnauth();
      const userState = wrapper.state('user');
      expect(userState).toEqual(null);
```

**Solution 2:**

Read the updated state in the callback parameter of `setState callback`

```
wrapper.setState({ user }, (userState) => {

      wrapper.instance().handleUnauth();
      //const userState = wrapper.state('user'); // comment it.
      expect(userState).toEqual(null);
});
```

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't have any effect but Solution 1 works perfectly for me. I think the callback was not needed because calling handleUnauth (component method) causes a state update. The updated state can then be compared in the assertion. Thanks Riyaj!

Comment: Thanks @Larrydx . Please upvote it if its working fine. Please let me know the error for solution 2

Comment: For solution 2 I was getting the same error that I have shown above in the question - not sure why. Decided to do some Enzyme tutorials to figure this out and will update once I have understood how/why.

Comment: OK.did you catching parameter in callback of setstate?

Comment: I’m glad that solution one works, but I’m a little confused since the quote from the docs doesn’t imply that you should remove the callback, but rather the opposite, that it wouldn’t work in the simple synchronous declarative way you’ve written it.